# How do I replace the contents of a JQuery.post request with a JS variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a jQuery.post request that has the contents in the form of a JS variable instead of hardcoded.

An example of before working in my system

```js
function builder() {
       jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', {
                    items: [
                        {
                            quantity: 1,
                            id: 100
                        }
                        ,{
                            quantity: 1,
                            id: 200
                        }
                    ]
                });
}
document.getElementById('someLink').href = "/cart";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="someLink" onclick="builder()"><input type="submit"
                    value="Click me" /></a>
```

What I am trying to do is have the whole contents of items and everything within the square brackets be in a JS variable instead that I can later call there.

A non-working example of how I'm trying to accomplish would look something like this:

```js
function builder() {

       var cartContents = "items: [{ quantity: 1, id: 100 } , { quantity: 1, id: 200 } ]";
       jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', {  
                    cartContents;   
                });
}
document.getElementById('someLink').href = "/cart";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="someLink" onclick="builder()"><input type="submit"
                    value="Click me" /></a>
```

That line "cartContents;" in the post function is where I know I'm wrong and I can't seem to find the right way to declare that JQuery variable in a way that simply inserts the contents of the variable's value. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: You literally just need to cut the entire `{ items: ... }` syntax and assign it to a variable, then use `jQuery.post('/cart.add.js', yourvariable);` in place of where it was.

Comment: You said "JS variable instead that I can later call". Does that mean you need to be able to access this same object at other points in your code?

Comment: By later call, I meant I was initializing the variable, that I'd then use in the jQuery post request. For your suggestion Taplar, for some hard to reproduce reason for me, your suggestion works 2/10 times when tested ten times. So it works!..sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're assigning cartContents as a string variable. Instead just make it a normal object and it will work. See below for working example:

```
function builder() {

   var cartContents = {
                      items: [
                              { quantity: 1, id: 100 } , 
                              { quantity: 1, id: 200 } 
                              ]
                      };
   jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', cartContents);
}
```